# Calling into my own DLL when depolyed on Azure

Tags: azure, dll, azure-web-app-service

I have a simple Windows Azure cloud service that does random number generation running on my local machine.  I have then published this to azure

```
    public string GetNumber()
    {
        Random number = new Random();
        return "number = " + number.Next(1, 100).ToString() + " number ";
    }
```

When I call this method from my client everything works fine.
ie

```
        ServiceReference1.RandomNumbersClient client = new ServiceReference1.RandomNumbersClient();

        Console.WriteLine("Starting .... ");
        Console.WriteLine(client.GetNumber());
```

Now,  the next step is I have added some code that requires "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Speech.dll" to be available in the project.  This is easy on my local server as I just add the reference to the dll in my VS project.

New method ....

```
    public string GetNumberAsString()
    {
        Random number = new Random();

        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();           
        synth.Speak("This example demonstrates a basic use of Speech Synthesizer");

        return "number = " + number.Next(1, 100).ToString() + " number ";
    }
```

Problem now is when I publish to Azure.  How do I make the DLL available to my app running in Azure?
When I call the GetNumber() method it works fine but any call to GetNumberAsString() fails because of the additional code.

```
        ServiceReference1.RandomNumbersClient client = new ServiceReference1.RandomNumbersClient();

        Console.WriteLine("Starting .... ");
        Console.WriteLine(client.GetNumberAsString());
```

How do I actually inspect the logs for the Webservice running on Azure so I can make a start at finding out what the problem is.

Comment: Have you set the DLL's `CopyLocal` property to true?

Comment: yes, set to true.  ( Edited OP with code )

Comment: Looking at your code, I'm guessing it has something to do with sound card. From what I know, Azure VM don't have the sound card installed.

Comment: Does it actually need specific hardware to perform the task I have added? I thought it would syntheize the text into speech using software only?  My goal is to stream the generated sound file back to the caller but one step at a time.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I guess only way to try it out is by commenting the `SpeechSynthesizer` related code and see if that works.

Comment: yea, the code runs fine without the SpeechSynthesizer code.  If I could see the logs then I could get a start at this but not much luck on that front

Comment: How are you deploying your service in Azure? Is it Web App, Cloud Service or in Virtual Machine? Diagnostics management would vary by that. Easiest way would be to catch the error by putting the code in try/catch block and return stack trace back to your program.

Comment: app is built as a cloud service and I just click "Publish" to push it into Azure.